# Find in Ansible and Save to a file

Tags: find, ansible

I want to save the result of `find` into the file with an Ansible play.

```
- name: Find / -name "postgresql"
  find:
    paths: /var/log
    patterns: 'postgresql'
```

The result of above will be saved into a file.
Simply, the command is `find / -name "postgresql" > text.txt` in shell.
How do I make that command in Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

An Ansible way of doing this with the [find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) could be (I am using `/var/log/secure` as an example since I don't run postgres):

```
---
- hosts: all 

  tasks:
  - name: "Find file /var/log/secure"
    find:
      paths: /var/log
      patterns: secure
    register: result

  - name: "Save find results to file"
    copy:
      content: "{{ result.files }}"
      dest: "/tmp/find_result.txt"
```

Content of `/tmp/find_result.txt`:

```
# cat /tmp/find_result.txt 
[{"uid": 0, "woth": false, "mtime": 1535012977.8429773, "inode": 9013905, "isgid": false, "size": 6867, "wgrp": false, "isuid": false, "isreg": true, "gid": 0, "ischr": false, "wusr": true, "xoth": false, "islnk": false, "nlink": 1, "issock": false, "rgrp": false, "path": "/var/log/secure", "xusr": false, "atime": 1534925281.706685, "isdir": false, "ctime": 1535012977.8429773, "isblk": false, "xgrp": false, "dev": 64768, "roth": false, "isfifo": false, "mode": "0600", "rusr": true}]
```

By registering the result, and checking the return value in `files`, you get access to a ton of metadata that might be useful.

If you want less output, use on of the other return values as documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-values).

Comment: the result is []
Check https://pastebin.com/xAHTNDEV

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Ansible shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/shell_module.html) in this case.

Here's an example:

```
- name: Find / -name "postgresql"
  shell: find / -name "postgresql" > /tmp/text.txt
```

Comment: aaahh i thought, i could make it without shell, just wanted to utilize "Find" task

Comment: Where do you want to have the output file written? Your localhost or your destination host?

Comment: After save into the file, i will run scp command to transfer that file into my other server